# "Cannot find symbol" error message calling super-class constructor

Tags: java

I have this error message

```
./MyCircle.java:13: cannot find symbol

symbol  : constructor MyEllipse(MyPoint,int,int)

location: class MyEllipse

super(position, radius*2, radius*2);
```

and my code is

```
public class MyCircle extends MyEllipse {

    final String TYPE = "Circle";

    public double radius;

    public MyCircle(int radius, MyPoint position) {
        super(position, radius*2, radius*2);
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public void printDetails() {
        double area = CalcArea();
        System.out.println("The shape is " +TYPE);
        System.out.println("The area is " +area);
    }
} // class end
```

Comment: What are the constructors of the `MyEllipse` class?

Comment: If you put more effort into asking your questions and actually marked correct answers, I would feel more inclined to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT says that there is no constuctor with

```
(position, radius*2, radius*2);
```

signature available in `MyEllipse`

---

you are calling

```
super(position, radius*2, radius*2);
```

Comment: ...or in other words, the signature `(MyPoint, int, int)`.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to call a constructor in `MyEllipse` which can take a `MyPoint` and two `int` values as arguments. The compiler is telling you it can't find such a constructor. It doesn't *have* to be of exactly that signature, of course. It could call

```
MyEllipse(Object, double, int)
MyEllipse(MyPoint, long, long)
```

or anything similar, so long as there are three parameters, and `MyPosition` can be assignment-converted to the first one, and `int` can be assignment-converted to the second and third.

(Strictly speaking there could also be a varargs constructor, but let's ignore that for the moment...)

We can't tell what's actually available without seeing the code for `MyEllipse`. Look at the constructors and check which one you actually want to call.

Answer (score 0):

We'd need to see the MyEllipse source. But I'd guess your problem is that there is no constructor in MyEllipse with the signature "MyPoint, int, int".