# cannot find symbol error in super constructor call

Tags: java

Compilation fails at line 8.  It says the "s" in "super" is wrong.

```
public class BasePlusCommissionEmployee extends CommissionEmployee {    
  private double baseSalary;

  //constructor
  public BasePlusCommissionEmployee( String first, String last, String ssn, int mth, 
          int day, int yr, double sales, double rate, double salary )
  {
     super( first, last, ssn, mth, day, yr, sales, rate );
     setBaseSalary( salary );
  }
```

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Comment: Are you having constructor with same number of arguments in your base class?? What exactly the Compiler says..

Comment: can you cut'n'paste the error message and show the relevant code for the CommissionEmployee class

Comment: Yes, you need to show the actual error message as it usually will tell you *exactly* what is wrong.

Comment: @llya.. copy 'n' paste you mean ?? :)

Comment: @Shinobi1173 - You should read SO's [Markdown Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) or use [the Formatting Reference provided when you are asking questions](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e29f4970b-pi) to ensure that your code snippets are readable.

Comment: Also "The code compiles except for line 8" just means the code doesn't compile at all ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Cannot find symbol" error message calling super-class constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276239/cannot-find-symbol-error-message-calling-super-class-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all likelihood,  you're not calling the super constructor, the constructor for the CommissionEmployee class, correctly, and are probably passing in the wrong parameters. Fix that and your error will likely go away.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is (and I'm pretty sure I'm blind right now), I cannot seem to find the dang thing

Comment: @Shinobi1173: then open your eyes. All you have to do is to inspect what parameters are needed for the CommisionEmployee constructor and only use those parameters when calling this constructor. The code is there for you to see (but not available to us at the moment).

Comment: Alright.  Found the problem.  Apparently, the order of listed arguments really matters.  Who knew?  Probably you.

Comment: @Shinobi1173: no, I didn't know, but the Java compiler did, and that's what matters! Glad you've got things working!

Comment: @Shinobi1173 imagine a function `drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {...`. And in the call: `drawRectangle(1,1,2,2);` If the order of the parameters would not be important, how should the compiler know which integer goes where?
Cheers!